# What is the purpose of restrict as size of array?

Tags: c, gcc, restrict-qualifier

I understand what `restrict` means, but I'm a little bit confused with such usage/syntax:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* foo(char s[restrict], int n)
{
        printf("%s %d\n", s, n);
        return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
        char *str = "hello foo";
        foo(str, 1);

        return 0;
}
```

Successfully compiled with `gcc main.c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic`

How is restrict work in this case and interpret by the compiler?

gcc version: 5.4.0

Comment: Must be the same as `restrict char *s`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits, or, `char * restrict s`?

Comment: It's buried in here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thank you for the correction. `restrict char *s` produces a compiler error; `char * restrict s` does not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all,

```
  char* foo(char s[restrict], int n) { ....
```

is the same as

```
  char* foo(char * restrict s, int n) {...
```

The syntax is allowed as per `C11`, chapter §6.7.6.2

> [...] The optional type qualifiers and the keyword `static` shall appear only in a
>   declaration of a function parameter with an array type, and then only in the outermost
>   array type derivation.

The purpose of having the `restricted` here is to hint the compiler that for every call of the function, the actual argument is **only** accessed via pointer `s`.

Comment: It's more than a hint. It's a promise, a contract between the function, the compiler, and calling code. Breaking it results in UB.

Answer (score 6):

From [restrict type qualifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict)

> In a function declaration, the keyword restrict may appear inside the square brackets that are used to declare an array type of a function parameter. It qualifies the pointer type to which the array type is transformed:

And example:

```
void f(int m, int n, float a[restrict m][n], float b[restrict m][n]);
```