How can I restrict array parameters in C (without making them pointers)?
Motivation
Array parameters can alias each other, and the compiler must carefully allow for this possibility. Thus, for example: GodBolt
int foo(int a[10], int b[10]) {
    a[0] += b[0];
    return a[0] + b[0];
}

int bar(int *a, int *b) {
    a[0] += b[0];
    return a[0] + b[0];
}

int baz(int * __restrict a, int * __restrict b) {
    a[0] += b[0];
    return a[0] + b[0];
}

the compiled code for foo() must be like that of bar(), not like that of baz().
Question
I want to use array parameters to my function - possibly even multi-dimension arrays (not arrays-of-pointers; the kind you declare with a pair of square brackets and decay to simple one-level pointers to the first element). And I also want the compiler to assume there is no aliasing, i.e. I want to mark my array parameters as restrict'ed.
How can I do this in C? And if I can't - why is that?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52724498/what-is-the-purpose-of-restrict-as-size-of-array

I don't follow. You can't pass an array to a function in C.  The language provides no way to express that.  When you specify a function argument that has array type, it is automatically converted to a pointer to the first array element, just like in almost all other expression contexts.  The function receives the pointer, and you can declare that pointer to be restricted if you like.

You understand that (1) and (2) are fully equivalent, right? Even if it turns out it's not possible with the array syntax (nevermind, apparently it's possible, see link above), you could still do int (*__restrict a)[42] instead of int a[10][42] to achieve the same thing.

@JohnBollinger: I don't intend to pass the array by value. It's "really" just a pointer that's passed. Question is, how do I declare that restriction, for an array parameter?

The first comment links to the answer, but the question is really about syntax sugar only.

@Mat: That seems to be answer. Marked it as a dupe.

No scare quotes needed.  It really is really just a pointer.  Which brings me back to not understanding the question.  What do you think is different about this situation from any other pointer-parameter situation that presents a complication for restrict?

@JohnBollinger: Like Eugene Sh said - just the syntax. It is not intuitive.

You can put qualifiers in the leftmost array declaration of a parameter (i.e. the part that gets converted to a pointer):
int foo(int a[restrict 10], int b[restrict 10]) {
    a[0] += b[0];
    return a[0] + b[0];
}


That does, indeed, seem to be the answer. But there's already a question with a similar answer, so I'm wondering whether to upvote & accept or not. Ah well, let's just do it.

Since I don't understand the significance the OP attributes to using array syntax instead of pointer syntax here, it seems prudent to note that unless static is among the given qualifiers, the numeric dimension in such a parameter declaration is not semantically meaningful.
